# How to trigger the onChange event in React after user stops typing for a specified time

Tags: reactjs

```
const Search = (query) => { 
  if (query != ""){ 
    let newLink = `/search?query=${query}`;
    window.location.href = `${newLink}`
  } 
}
```

I cant finish typing because of the onChange function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `onBlur`:

```
export default function App() {
  const doThis = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onBlur={doThis} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

After clicking out of the input, the event will occur.

---

**Edit**

From your comments, it looks like you are trying to detect a delay in typing to trigger a callback. Not sure how robust this is but I made a [sample codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/detect-stop-typing-fzuij).

We just call a `setTimeout` with a delay after updating the input. Then within the callback we can look at the time between when it was set and the current time. If the user makes another keystroke, the `lastUpdate` will get updated and therefore the `diff` will be small by the time the `setTimeout` executes.

```
import { useState } from "react";

let lastUpdate;

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
    lastUpdate = Date.now();

    setTimeout(() => {
      const diff = Date.now() - lastUpdate;

      if (diff > 500) {
        console.log("Search!");
      }
    }, 500);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={handleChange} value={text} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but the function doesn't trigger if I do not click outside in the input tag.

Comment: What kind of event do you want to trigger it?

Comment: I want an event like this https://www.getwatch.in/ just try to search something

Comment: I want to trigger my function when I finish typing.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an event for this. I think you are going to have to build a timer of some sort. It will need to check the time between keystrokes and if they exceed a certain amount, then call the search. I'll try to create a sample for you.

Comment: Check out the edit to my answer @Pusoy